# Fixing the "app is required" error in AWS CDK

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to run this function:

```
"cdk deploy --require-approval never"
```

but I am getting this error:

```
--app is required either in command-line, in cdk.json or in ~/.cdk.json
```

How can I fix this? Here's what I have in my cdk.json file:

```
{
  "app": "npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts bin/project-infra.ts",
}
```

And here's my project infrastructure code:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
// import * as sqs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';

export class ProjectInfraStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const layer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, "BaseLayer", {
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("lambda_base_layer/layer.zip")
      compatibleRuntimes: [lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9],

    });

    const apiLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "ApiFunction", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("../main_app/"),
      handler: "main.handler",
      layers: [layer], 
    });
    
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to instantiate your stack in the scope of an app in addition to declaring the stack class.

Answer (score 14):

This message usually means that you aren't in the main directory of your AWS CDK project when you issue cdk synth. The file cdk.json in this directory, created by the cdk init command, contains the command line needed to run (and thereby synthesize) your AWS CDK app. For a TypeScript app the default cdk.json looks something like this:

```
{
  "app": "npx ts-node bin/my-cdk-app.ts"
}
```

This is a common issue that is described in the CDK documentation:

[Troubleshooting common AWS CDK issues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting_app_required)

Answer (score 1):

it looks like `ProjectInfraStack` is a `cdk.Stack`, it needs to be within a `cdk.App`.

```js
// bin/project-infra.ts or you can move this declaration to its dedicated bin/main.ts. remember to update cdk.json if so.
const app = new cdk.App();

const myStack = new ProjectInfraStack(
  app,
  'myStack',
  {
    env: env,
    description: 'my project infra stack',
    ... // other props
  },
);

export class ProjectInfraStack extends cdk.Stack {
  ... // stack definition
}
```

Comment: @payday17 The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/apps.html) explain why you need an `App`, which is the _"only construct that can be used as a root for the construct tree"_.  App > Stacks > Other Constructs.